# how to set laptop win7 as a router using ICS?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, home-networking, ics

I have Windows 7 Ultimate in a laptop which I use internet with my wireless connection I have another connection which is local area connection I set the default gateway my another laptop
I want My another laptop to see internet via cable
by the help of our friend now I found sharing tab in the wireless connection now please tell me what's wrong and why still I can't connect the cabled one to the internet?
two laptops can ping each other because I set the local area connection tcp/ip Ip addresses in one class

```
laptop1 with no internet:
IP:192.168.137.2
laptop2 with internet via wireless:
IP:192.168.137.1
gateway:192.168.137.2
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I should set IP addresses automatically let me try!

Comment: I don't know what should i do now.I tried to set IP automatically but I don't know why for ICS in the help it should be automatic then how another laptop will connect without using gateway it is weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong screen, you need to go to Change Adapter Settings in the sidebar and right click your adapter.

[image]

Comment: I went to wireless in the part you told me and in sharing I set the network as local area connection but still it can't see the internet

Comment: I found the problem it was from XP which had remote access I was mistakenly set default gateway on the local which was incorrect I should set it in the 1394 connection hurrraaaaay:)